# Installing PHP without webserver for IDE Linting while programming

Tags: php, linux, installation, development-environment

My IDE (atom.io) is on my main system. I already have a web-server with PHP running that has drives mounted onto my local machine. I don't want my local machine (running Pop_OS linux) to have the overhead of running a server (It's my main home computer, I use it for lots of other things too, including some intensive gaming).

Now, in the past, I've always just dealt with the fact, but I've decided that's not best for my workflow. But I've been wondering... is there a way to install php without the webserver so it's only invoked when my IDE is linting it? So far I've looked around, and all I can find are instructions for having a localhost server, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks.

Comment: you can turn the webserver on and off as required - just like any other program. but yes you can run php solely as invoked from a command line call

Comment: @tim Yes, but that requires turning it on and off (and remembering to). I'm more wanting to not have to deal with it in the first place by not installing it. Every install instructions I've seen for PHP comes with the web server. I'm wanting to skip that part. Is there a flag for that when doing sudo apt-get install php? Will installing it without apache or similar break it?

Comment: whats forcing you to install a web server? I've never seen this issue.

Comment: Maybe I've just been at it too long, but from what I've seen, php has the dependency of apache, and apache installs include a webserver.

Comment: `apt-get install php php-MySQL -y` ? (if you want MySQL support) no webserver (well php has a  built-in one)

Comment: ... well... that definately installed apache and it's webserver at the same time... so that wasn't it.

Comment: why do you think that installed apache? because it won't.

Comment: Because after I ran apt-get install php php-MySQL -y, among the first lines in the terminal were `The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2 ...` and once it ran, there was a now a shiny new webpage telling me I have an apache server when I point my browser at localhost.

Comment: thats a support package, not apache itself

Comment: The full list of programs it added looked like all of the apache programs: `  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap php-common php7.2
  php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline`